AVD of Android Studio Ladybug keeps "starting up..." until it reached time out and nothing happen
I have installed Android Studio Ladybug 2024.2.1 Patch 3 in my laptop, the installation went well and it works just fine. But when I tried to run a virtual device (AVD) it keeps hanging in "starting up..." until it reached time out (a pop up window shows up). But the process of "qemu" emulator still running in task manager, so in order to re-run it I have to kill the process and remove all the ".lock" files in the AVD's dir.
But sometimes, the AVD will run well when the laptop first boot up, but when I stop the AVD and re-run it again the problem presists. What could be the problem?
This is my laptop's specs:

Intel Core i5 8th gen (i5-8265U)
NVIDIA Geforce MX-150
Windows 11 Home Edition
20GB DDR4 RAM
1TB m.2 NVME SSD

What I have tried to resolve this problem:

Reinstalling all the SDK and ADK Tools needed
Reinstalling the Android Studio (clean install)
Manually running it using terminal
Installing the accelerator (intel HAXM) and switching between HAXM and Windows Hypervisor Platform (not Hyper-V because Windows 11 Home Edition doesn't support it)
Using lower API SDK for the AVD (android 10)
Create a new bootable windows 11 with a clean install and only installing only Android Studio

Hope I can find the solution here, thank you for your helps.
